# Project files are not showing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I Just cloned android project from the bitbucket which doesnot contains  gradle folder in it.
I imported it as an eclipse project in my android studio but problem is I cannot see any files when I select **android** from the top left corner drop down menu but some files are seen under **project** menu.

doesn't show any files.[image: here]

shows some of files only.[image: here]

Comment: try to select other options from the top left corner drop down menu

Comment: only project menu shows files but other menu doesnot show any files.

Answer (score 0):

check the settings.gradle and add this line and save include ':app'**

Comment: include ':app'    add this